# How to detect when a file has been downloaded?

Tags: node.js, file, watch

How in NodeJS can I detect when file has been downloaded?
I'm using fs.watch method, but callback is called too many times

```
    fs.watch(`./${IMAGES_FOLDER}/${filename}`, () => {
      if (!isDownloaded) {
        const output = fs.createWriteStream(`${DOWNLOAD_FOLDER}/${filename}.zip`)
        const archive = archiver('zip')
    
        archive.pipe(output)
        archive.directory(`images/${filename}`, false)
        archive.on('error', err => {throw err})
        archive.finalize()
            
        output.on('close', () => {
          resp.download(downloadUrl)
        })
            
        archive.on('error', (err) => {
          throw err
        })
      }
    
      isDownloaded = true
  })
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand the logic behind this. Shouldn't it be `if (!isDownloaded) {...`?

Comment: Downloaded by what and how?  Downloaded through a web server?  If so, then you will want to hook into the web server itself to see when it's downloaded, not hook directly into the file system.

Comment: I'm using Puppeteer to download a file and I have to wait until the file is downloaded.
In this case, it executes the archiver before the file is downloaded (it also has the .crdownload extension)